# How to fetch currency flags from API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I built a currency converter and want to display next to currency abbreviation the flag also! I fetch the currency rates from API but cannot find how can I display the flags next to them! I tried to create a script.js file including the flags but didn't work! I guess is quite easy however I have spent a lot of time to find a way!

[Converter Application Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3yHY.jpg)

Code for Converter component:

````
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { 
      currencyInput: 'USD',
      currencyOutput: 'EUR',
      amountInput: 0,
      amountOutput: 0,
      options: []
    }
 }


handleChange = event => {
  const target = event.target
  const value = target.value
  const name = target.name

this.setState({ [name]: value })
}

handleSubmit = event => {
  event.preventDefault () //Preventing form from submitting

fetch(`http://api.exchangeratesapi.io/v1/latest?access_key=my-token`)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {
  const rateFromEuroToInput = data.rates[this.state.currencyInput] 
  const inputInEuros = this.state.amountInput / rateFromEuroToInput
  const rateFromEuroToOutput = data.rates[this.state.currencyOutput]
  const eurosInOutput = inputInEuros * rateFromEuroToOutput
  
this.setState({ amountOutput: eurosInOutput })
  })
}

componentDidMount() {
  fetch(`http://api.exchangeratesapi.io/v1/latest?access_key=API KEY`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    const currencyOptions = Object.keys(data.rates)

  this.setState({ options: currencyOptions })
  })
}


render() {
  return (
    <>
    <div className="card card-body p-3 mb-3 bg-light text-dark">
      <h1 className="mb-4">Currency Converter</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div className="d-flex">
          <div className="form-row col-md-6 col-sm-6 offset-1">
            <div className="form-group col-md-8">
              <div className="mb-2">
                <label><strong>Currency I Have</strong></label>
              </div>
              <select className="form-select"
                type="text"
                name='currencyInput'
                value={this.state.currencyInput}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              >
                {this.state.options.map(option => {
                  return <option value={option}>{option}</option>
                  })
                }
              </select>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group col-md-8 mt-4">
              <div className="mb-2">
              <label><strong>Amount</strong></label>
              </div>
              <input className="form-control"
               name="amountInput"
               type="number"
               value={this.state.amountInput}
               onChange={this.handleChange} 
               />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-row col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div className="form-group col-md-8">
              <div className="mb-2">
                <label><strong>Currency I Want</strong></label>
              </div>
              <select className="form-select"
               type="text"
               name='currencyOutput'
               value={this.state.currencyOutput}
               onChange={this.handleChange} 
               >
              {this.state.options.map(option => {
                return <option value={option}>{option}</option>
                })
              }
              </select>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group col-md-8 mt-4">
              <div className="mb-2">
                <label><strong>Amount</strong></label>
              </div>
              <input className="form-control"
                name="amountOutput"
                type="number" 
                value={this.state.amountOutput}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary mb-2">Convert</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
    )
  }
}
export default Converter```

I would like to give any suggestion how to implement the flags with in the currency rows!
Thank you!
````

Comment: Where do you get the flags?

Comment: @Sinan Yaman That's the point of the question! I fetch the currency rates dynamically but cannot find a way to correspond flags next to them? I have no flags in my project yet!

Comment: Seems like your question needs a little bit more focus. The provided code contributes nothing to the question if that is the case. Try looking at some libraries like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-flags)

Answer (score 0):

you can fix this by downloading all the currencies images that you will use, and after that create an object which bind `key: symbol; value: 'path-to-image'`

[Please refer to this on how to display icon inside input](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/css-to-put-icon-inside-an-input-element-in-a-form/)

And [Refer to this on how to include images in React](https://daveceddia.com/react-image-tag/)

As far as I am looking at this, concrete solution might be like this

```js
// * Download all currency flags that you will use and add them to public directory

const mapSymbolToFlag = {
    'ALL': 'path-to-public-directory/all.ico',
    'EUR': 'path-to-public-directory/eur.ico'
}

// * so on and so forth
```

Create an input component to hide all the details on how to put image/icon on input and the mapping, and include this input component that you will create on the main currency component with **symbol as input/prop**

Answer (score 0):

I have a few points I want to highlight:

- A way to solve this is creating a dictionary where you can define a flag using the currency.
- Creating a component where you send the currency can be a good practice to implement the dictionary
- There are currencies where many countries use them, so in this case you need to define a flag or adapt your component to show the flags where the currency applies.
- In your example you are overriding the state and deleting the information of your initial state, you need to add setState({...state, }) and after that, new things.

Here are my code snippets where you need to modify:

```js
...
handleChange (event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    // add `...state` to avoid remove all your previous information
    setState({ ...state, [name]: value });
  };
...
```

```js
...
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //Preventing form from submitting

    fetch(`http://api.exchangeratesapi.io/v1/latest?access_key=my-token`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      const rateFromEuroToInput = data.rates[state.currencyInput]
      const inputInEuros = state.amountInput / rateFromEuroToInput
      const rateFromEuroToOutput = data.rates[state.currencyOutput]
      const eurosInOutput = inputInEuros * rateFromEuroToOutput

      // add ...state to avoid remove all your previous information
      setState({ ...state, amountOutput: eurosInOutput })
    })
  };
...
```

```js
...
render() {
  <>
      <div className="card card-body p-3 mb-3 bg-light text-dark">
        <h1 className="mb-4">Currency Converter</h1>

        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="d-flex">
            <div className="form-row col-md-6 col-sm-6 offset-1">
              <div className="form-group col-md-8">
                <div className="mb-2">
                  <label>
                    <strong>Currency I Have</strong>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <select
                  className="form-select"
                  type="text"
                  name="currencyInput"
                  value={state.currencyInput}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                >
                  {state.options.map((option) => {
                    return <option value={option}>{option}</option>;
                  })}
                </select>
                {/* HERE GOES YOUR NEW COMPONENT */}
                <Flags currency={state.currencyInput} />
              </div>
...
}
```

I found an image API where you can define a flag using its country code
[Country flags](https://www.countryflags.io/)

Using that I made this component

```js
import React from 'react';
import flagsData from '../../mocks/flags.json';

const FLAG_URL = 'https://www.countryflags.io';
const { flagsFromCurrency, styles, sizes } = flagsData;

const Flags = ({ currency, style = styles.FLAT, size = sizes['16'] }) => {
  return (
    <img
      src={`${FLAG_URL}/${flagsFromCurrency[currency]}/${style}/${size}.png`}
      alt={flagsFromCurrency[currency]}
    />
  );
};

export default Flags;
```

This is the result:

[image]

And you can take a look at the code I made [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-drksxo?file=src/App.js)

I hope this works for you.

**Update**: I implemented bootstrap styles.